# how to responsive the google sign in button

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, google-signin

I am working with google sign in and using [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) this package. I have the following code in react

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google'


const GoogleSigninHelper = (props) => {
    const clientId = 'MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'
    return (
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={clientId}>
            <GoogleLogin
                onSuccess={props.googleLogin}
                size='medium'
                logo_alignment='left'
            />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    )
}

export default GoogleSigninHelper
```

In this code, google sign in button gets smaller once the component renders. I know I can pass width as props to `<GoogleLogin />`. If I pass width (e.g. 350px), the button is not responsive and the width always fixed to that width (350px).

How can I make google sign in button responsive for all devices? Or how can I use custom button here?

Please anyone can help me with valuable suggestions?